# mplayer mute stdout and supress get focus on loop

Tags: mplayer

I use this

```
type mplayer
mplayer is aliased to `mplayer -fs -noconsolecontrols -loop 0'
```

to play files. I would like to mute the stdout stuff so I could keep bash to do other things by running mplayer with `&`.
This worked with GNOME 2 but since I updated to sid something went wrong.

```
MPlayer svn r34540 (Debian), built with gcc-4.6 (C) 2000-2012 MPlayer Team
```

Another thing:

When replaying after full cycle (the loop flag above) the window with the media that looped gets on top of everything else.

Like, if I watch a Survivor episode with no sound, and then play music videos in the background (that is, two mplayer processes), the music video gets focus at each new iteration.

Is there a way to turn this off but still keep the looping on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To silence the output you could use shell IO redirection, either of:

   ```
   mplayer -noconsolecontrols <options> 2>&- 1>/dev/null &
   mplayer -slave <options> 2>&- 1>/dev/null &
   ```
2. The `-fixed-vo` option should make mplayer reuse the same window thus fixing the focus grabbing.

This is based on the man page included with:

```
MPlayer 1.0rc2-4.3.2-DFSG-free (C) 2000-2007 MPlayer Team
```

Yes, that is Debian lenny's mplayer.

Comment: 1. This disabled the audio, that wasn't my intention but to not have the stdout debug stuff so I could run mplayer from bash with & and then do other things in the terminal window. 2. -fixed-vo did work, thanks

Comment: Ah, I've updated the answer with a solution that works and that I've tested for 1

Comment: Right, I had forgotten about that solution. Cool 2>1 :) Alright, problem solved.

Comment: Actually, the 2>1 doesn't seem to work. It thinks it is a file name so a file named 1 is created. Of course, 2> /dev/null will do it.

Comment: I was mistaken in the syntax for IO redirection ([ref](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html)) but that has been corrected. And I found after testing that if I didn't add the `-slave` option, mplayer wouldn't play when backgrounded.

Comment: Yeah? It works for me, maybe because of -noconsolecontrols?

Comment: Yup, that option works too.